Evaluating $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\left(\frac{\log x}x\right)^{1/\log x}$
Isn't the limit to $0$ from the right side to this function $\left(\frac{\log x}x\right)^{1/\log x}$ undefined? then why in graphing calculators the answer is 1/e?
I tried finding the limit of this function and it always came undefined, but when I graph the function it is approaching $1/e$. can you help me find why. I tried using l'hopital's rule but its definition doesn't apply here.

Your function is undefined on $(0, 1)$ since $\frac{\log x}{x}$ is negative there, so it makes no sense to raise it to power $\frac{1}{\log x}$. A fortiori, there is no limit at $0^+$.
